# При парсинге получаю пустой массив. Как получить нужные мне картинки?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Я пытаюсь спарсить картинки с сайта по url https://amirowrafael.ru/marat-guliya

При попытки получить дивы с картинками я получаю пустой массив. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://amirowrafael.ru/marat-guliya"

response = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', class_= 'section-container')
all_image = block.find_all('div',class_='piece')


print(all_image)
```

Вот сама структура дом дерева
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Динамический сайт, рекомендую вам использовать селенимум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищете div с классом section-container, в html на скриншоте такого не видно.